# Can Lambda layer be used to manipulate the data and shape of the input?

Tags: keras

I want to create a new network out of two existing networks (models) A and B using Keras with tensorflow. Architecture of new network is like this

Input -> A -> B -> Output

The output of A has shape of (15, 500) and input of B has a shape of (1000). I have a conversion method that takes the input of shape (15, 100) and call predict of a completely different network (C), and return the output with the shape of (1000).

I am assuming that I have to introduce a Lambda layer which will use my conversion method to convert the output of A to a format required for B. But, when I tried that, I get error

"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Dimension' and 'float'_" on calling predict in the conversion method.

This is the conversion method

```
def convert(x):
    C = load_model("path/to/the/network/C.h5")
    return C.predict(x)
```

I am not sure if this is the right way of doing, if it is, then why is this error. If it is not the right way, then, what should be my approach.

Keras version: 2.0.1
Tensorflow version: 1.0.1

Thanks,

Comment: No, that `convert` method is not going to work if C is a going to be a trainable network. We need more details, what is the architecture of C?

Comment: @putonspectacles I have an auto-encoder with RNN layers. It's architecture is (Input -> Dropout -> LSTM -> Dense -> Dense -> RepeatVector -> LSTM). C has the first 5 layers to get the output from the encoder layer. That is, C = Model(input, model.get_layer('dense_2').output)

Comment: ok, so you have 3 networks A, B, C, your goal is to train a network D: Input ->  A -> B -> Output . But, while training D you also want to take the predictions (on Input) from  C  as part of the transformation in the network.  Did I get that right?

Comment: You got it correct!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that you are not trying to train the C in as part of the new network (lets call it D). This what I imagine you want

```
 A
 | 
(C) # transform step. a non-trainable keras model
 |
 B
 |
out
```

*Note the variables names are from the examples in the **original answer** section*.

**Update**, Yes the code in **orginal answer** only uses the `dense_2` layer from `model_1`.

This is not what you want, so I went digging. And beautifully, the answer is simple.

- load C and its weights,
- update the outputs of the model so that we can set an arbitrary layer as the output.
- set the layers of C to not be trainable using `layer.trainable = False`.
- Finally, call the *transform* model like you would a layer `model_1(inp2)`

Here is the example in the original answer updated, to prove that weights in C are not trainable we'll print `model_1.summary()`

```
# let `model_1` be C in the diagram above.
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import (Lambda, Dense, Input)

inp = Input(shape=(5, ))
lam = Lambda(lambda x: x + 2, name='lamb')(inp)
den = Dense(1, name='dense')(lam) # this is the `model_1` output
model_1 = Model(inp, den)

# suppose we want an intermediate output from model_1
# (the `lam` layer for instance)
# we update the outputs and use that output in model2

model.outputs = [model.output,  model.get_layer(name='lamb').output]
print(model.outputs)

# [<tf.Tensor 'dense_11/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>,
# <tf.Tensor 'lamb_9/add:0' shape=(?, 5) dtype=float32>]

# now build D, since we can treat a model like a layer( awesome!) 
# we can just let models A, B in the diagram above be layers 
# (for this exmple) - nothing changes.

# But first set the layers of `model_1` to not be trainable:

print(model_1.summary()) # Trainable params: 6.0 - before
for l in model_1.layers:
    l.trainable = False 
print(model_1.summary()) # Trainable params: 0.0  - after

# ...then D is:

inp2 = Input(shape=(5, ))     # imagine that this layer is model A
transform = model_1(inp2)[1]  # this is (C) the transform step. 
                              # Notice that we pulled out the lambda 
                              # output by using the index into the
                              # `model_1's` outputs.

# carry on as normal
den2 = Dense(1)(transform) # imagine that this is B
model_2 = Model(inp2, den2)
model_2.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model_2.summary()

# simulate data
X = np.random.randn(10, 5)
y = np.random.randn(10, 1)

# fit D
model_2.fit(X, y)  # ... it trains!
```

A few notes:

- we are not going to be calling compile since we dont need to
  configure  the model for training. See doc string of [`compile()`](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/9eb7ecd3e525c9cff31ebd59a96794f212ca5e1e/keras/engine/training.py#L677) 
  or equivalently the [keras docs](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#compilation)
- However, if we load the model with `keras.models.load_model`.
  that model is compiled but it should not have any affect since we are
  going to use `layer.trainable = False`. See doc string for [`save()`](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/9eb7ecd3e525c9cff31ebd59a96794f212ca5e1e/keras/engine/topology.py#L2423)

**Original  Answer**

Instead of returning a the prediction with is an array, grab the output the last layer of C.

```
def convert(x):
    # there is not need to load C in the lambda layer.
    # load it somewhere outside of the training op.
    # assuming you have C loaded...
    return C.get_layer('dense_2')(x)
```

Here is a quick example of this approach: Note that you will have to make
sure that the layers shape are compatible.

you can imagine that this is mode C

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import (Lambda, Dense, Input)

inp = Input(shape=(5,))
lam = Lambda(lambda x: x + 2, name='lamb')(inp)
den = Dense(1, name='dense')(lam) # this is the `model_` output
model_1 = Model(inp, den)
model_1.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
```

we're going to grab the output of the `lam` layer
and use that as transformation step in D below:

```
inp2 = Input(shape=(5, ))
# grab the 'dense' layer from `model_1` 
sums = Lambda(lambda x: model_1.get_layer(name='dense')(x))(inp2)
den2 = Dense(1)(sums)
model_2 = Model(inp2, sums)
model_2.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model_2.summary()
```

Comment: In transform step, I want the output of the sub-set of the model C (first few layers), not just n-th layer. That is, if trained network C has layers C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4 -> C5 -> C6 -> C7, I would like to use the output of the sub-model (C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4 - C5) in my D. Your example above, in D network,  you just take the 'dense' layer, where as I am thinking that we need to consider all the layers prior to the network.

Comment: Just correcting last sentence in my previous commend. "Your example above, in D network, you just taking the 'dense' layer, where as I am thinking that we need to consider all the layers prior to the 'dense' layer"

Comment: I am thinking that your original answer would work with a little change. The layer in D, 'sums = Lambda(lambda x: model_1.get_layer(name='dense')(x))(inp2)', can be replaced with  'sums = Lambda(lambda x: intermediate_model(x))(inp2)' where intermediate layer is Model(C.input, C.get_layer('dense').output). I am assuming that the lambda layer by default is not trainable. But, not sure though. I will mark the trainable flag false and try.

Comment: @Fasil so the new answer did not work for you? what problems did you bump into?

Comment: I did not try the new answer yet. I tried with your original suggestion with the little changes I mentioned in the previous post. The training is going on. I will definitely try the new answer and post the result here once I am done with the training.  Thank you so much for the answers.